# Getting Gradle to use an artifact from a local maven repository

Tags: maven, gradle

I want to use a maven repository with cached artifacts that I have on my local computer to accelerate the Gradle build by avoiding downloading them.

Unfortunately, what I notice is that even though the local repository is listed first and it has the dependency I need, Gradle will fetch the artifact from the Internet if an Internet connection is available and will only use the local repository if there is a problem getting to the network one.

Here is one concrete small example that reproduces this issue:

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  maven {
    name 'cache'
    url "/home/vagrant/m2copy"
  }
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
}

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Created-By': 'Ekumen'
  }
}
```

The contents of **/home/vagrant/m2copy**:

```
m2copy:
com

m2copy/com:
google

m2copy/com/google:
code

m2copy/com/google/code:
gson

m2copy/com/google/code/gson:
gson

m2copy/com/google/code/gson/gson:
2.4

m2copy/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.4:
gson-2.4.jar
gson-2.4.jar.sha1
_remote.repositories
```

And the output of a gradle build:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/test_cache$ ./gradlew build
:compileJava
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.4/gson-2.4.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/9/oss-parent-9.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.4/gson-2.4.jar
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Any ideas why is Gradle skipping the local repository on this case and only using it when there is no access to jcenter?

Comment: Try to add -i to your build command to get more information. Gradle will tell you which repositories it is trying to access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you might be missing the .pom descriptor files in your cache and maybe some other .xml descriptors. Try to get the .pom file for your dependency and see if that helps.

Comment: That was exactly it. The mechanism I was using to generate the local repository was leaving out the .pom files and that would get Gradle to use this repository only as a back-up.